# Need to access all text within the divs and change the color of the text to white

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble acessing all the text within the divs including h and p tags and changing the text color to white. The button should toggle ALL the text within the page to the color white. I tried using querySelectorAll("div textContent") but it's not working.

```js
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
var textColorWhite = function(){
 for (var el of document.querySelectorAll("div textContent"))
    el.classList.toggle("fontColorWhite");  
}
window.onload = function () {
    $("textColor").addEventListener("click", textColorWhite);
}
```

```css
.fontColorWhite{
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div>
           <h1>One</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur adipisicing elit</a>. Perspiciatis magni reprehenderit quibusdam ipsam eius odit iste consequatur necessitatibus voluptatibus deserunt maxime esse, similique, cupiditate facere quis <a href="#">quos id</a> delectus est.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
           <h2>Two</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">adipisicing elit</a>. Autem magni voluptatibus tempore aut corrupti, ducimus optio consequuntur. Quasi debitis a dicta natus <a href="#">voluptas</a> alias ea, quis excepturi ut, eius accusantium.</p>
        </div>
        <section>
            <button type="button" id="textColor">Change Text Color</button>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.querySelectorAll("div textContent")` looks for `<textContent>` elements that are a child of a `<div>` element.

Comment: `for (var el of document.querySelectorAll("div"))`

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._